# $s := \sup(\{a_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\})$ and $s =\limsup_{n \to ∞} a_n$ at the same time

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$(a_n)_{n=0}^∞$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, $ s := \sup(\{a_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\})$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Proof the following: If $a_n \ne s$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $s = \limsup_{n \to ∞} a_n$.

I have two points here that I do not really understand.

The first thing is that there is no $a_n$ for which $a_n = s$ while at the same time $ s = \sup(\{a_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\})$. It seems as if $s$ has the value of the highest $a_n$ while the highest $a_n$ does not have the value of $s$.

The second point is that I thought that I thought that $\limsup_{n \to ∞} a_n < \sup(\{a_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\})$ if $a_n \ne \mathit{const}$ and if $a_n = \mathit{const}$ then $a_n = s$.

Can somebody explain what I understand wrong?

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is false. I suspect you left out one of the hypotheses. I could guess, but better you should actually state the question correctly...

Comment: @David: Looks true to me. Do you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: This are all the hypotheses there are. I checked it once again, this is the original problem.

Comment: Eewps! No counterexample, sorry. When I see "$\limsup=\sup$" I automatically say hmm, that happens if $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$. Missed the significance of $a_n\ne s$. I lied. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the supremum is.

As an example, let's take $a_n=1-1/n$, so
$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(0,\frac12,\frac23,\frac 34,\ldots)$$

The supremum of this sequence is $1$, because $1\ge a_n$ for all $n$, and *there is no smaller number that is $\ge$ every element of the sequence*.

This example shows that $\sup\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ does not need to be an element of the sequence. And indeed the property you have to prove is true about this sequence: $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n= 1$.

This also shows that your second point is false: The limsup and sup can be the same even though the sequence is not constant. It is not clear how you got the impression that they can't, so I cannot help pinpoint your misunderstanding any further.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I think I understand the problem now.